# Find the number of pairs of integer $(x,y)$ with $0<x,y<10$ that satisfy $\frac{1}{1-\frac{10}{x}} > 1 - \frac{5}{y}.$

Tags: inequality

Find the number of pairs of integers $(x,y)$ with $0<x,y<10$ that satisfy$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{10}{x}} > 1 - \frac{5}{y}.$$

I simplified the equation until I got $x+2y < 10.$
Solving for $x$ and $y$ gives $x < 10-2y$ and $y < 10-x/2.$
I'm stuck on how to continue.

Comment: I would be happy with a hint on how to continue. :)

Comment: The first two inequalities are wrong. Surprisingly the third inequality presented is correct!

Comment: Oh oops, my first two inequalities was from my first work, which was wrong. Sorry! I'll edit my question.

Comment: There's so few try them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two steps are wrong, but surprisingly the third inequality given $\ x+2y<10 $ is correct. I will continue from there. Note that $\ 1-\frac{5}{y} $ is negative because $\ 1-\frac{10}{x} $ is negative. Hence, $\ y<5$, $\ y$ belongs to $\ {(1,2,3,4)} $. If $\ y=4$, we get $\ x=1$, $\ y=3$, $\ x$ belongs to $\ (1,2,3)$, $\ y=2$, $\ x$ belongs to $\ (1,2,3,4,5)$, $\ y=1$, $\ x$ belongs to $\ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$. Hence total number of solutions is $\ 1+3+5+7=16$. I obviously think there is a better approach. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!